# Dictionary with a List<> as TValue

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to create a Dictionary, the TKey is a string and the TValue is a `List<DateTime>`

How can I do this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>();
```

Note that, when adding new items, you need to allocate a new list for the value:

```
string key; // assuming that's your key
List<DateTime> value;
if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out value)) {
    value = new List<DateTime>();
    dict.Add(key, value);
}
// value is now always a valid instance
```

Comment: OOOOoooops ..... Am I drunk ? .... probably I tried this, but was probably not exactly this :). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>();
```

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>
```

Comment: You probably have to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>> oDictionary;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like:

```
Dictionary<String, List<DateTime>> myDict = new Dictionary<String, List<DateTime>>();
```